# arrange multi-dimensional array webapp dropdown dependent

Tags: html, arrays, sorting, web-applications

I make a function to load an array to dataset from googlesheets.
The data like this

[datasource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgS8B.png)

My code is

```
function getObject(){
  const obj ={}
  const id = ''; 
  const name = 'LOV';
  const data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(name).getDataRange().getDisplayValues().slice(1);

  data.forEach( ( [subjectKey, topicKey, chapter]) => {
      const subject = obj[subjectKey]
      if (!subject) {
        obj[subjectKey] ={}
        obj[subjectKey][topicKey] = [chapter]
        } else{
        const topic = subject[topicKey]
        if (!topic) {
          subject[topicKey] = [chapter]
        } else{
          topic.push(chapter)
        }
      }
  })
  console.log(obj);
  //return obj;
}
```

But the result is not sort by ascending like I sent. It can be b c a or random.

And when I make dropdown menu html Level 1 and 2 not ascending

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r23Qy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sql8e.png)

It only ascending all level 3 dropdown
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpRBl.png)

The result I would like to show like this

`{ 'An Giang':  { 'Huyện An Phú':  [ 'Thị trấn An Phú', 'Thị Trấn Long Bình', 'Xã Đa Phước', 'Xã Khánh An', 'Xã Khánh Bình', 'Xã Nhơn Hội', 'Xã Phú Hội', 'Xã Phú Hữu', 'Xã Phước Hưng',`

Please help to advice method how to return obj in ascending order